# Styling n-th child w.r.t host-context in angular

Tags: css, angular

I m creating a custom-toaster component using ngx-toastr. For the custom component, I dont have access to the toaster container. All the toasts that are created need to be stacked in the toaster container. The toasts are aligned to the top right corner ( through top css property). I have styled the toaster container using host-context as it not available in custom component and it comes from library.

It works well, but the problem occurs when there are more than one toasts. Since they are style based on the host-context, all the toasts will have the same value for top-css property.

Say if each toast's height is 40px, am not able to customize the top value based on nth-child property w.r.t host-context. Has any one faced a similar issue ? Any help is appreciated.

```css
:host-context(.toast-top-right.toast-container):nth-child{
    top: calc(66 + ( n * 40))px; 
    right: 12px;
}
```

Please find the illustration here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7ancy
Try clicking on test multiple times, observe the divs created inside 'overlay-container'

Comment: Can you share an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: @aloisdg :I have updated with stackblitz link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@August The suggestion helped. This more to do with position property. I have solved it as shown below

```css
:host-context(.toast-container){
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  :host(.toast-success){
    border-left-color: #51A351;   
    position:relative
  }
```

Comment: Glad if I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of positioning each toastr to top: 66px right: 12px I would position `.toast-container` and let all the toastr items flow in a default block manner.

```
.toast-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 66px;
    right: 12px;
}

.toast[_nghost-c2] {
    position: relative;
}
```

Looks like the css definitions from toastr.component.scss are not applied in that manner. In order to apply the css definitions I went ahead and did:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkefn9?file=src%2Fcustom-toastr%2Ftoastr.component.ts

Comment: Does this apply in Angular with View Encapsulation ? Are you able to  run this in stackblitz example ?